# MOSFET not saturating when Vds > Vgs - Vth

Tags: mosfet, nmos, saturation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Triode_mode_or_linear_region_(also_known_as_the_ohmic_mode)), the drain current (\$I_d\$) should stay relatively constant when \$V_{ds} > V_{gs} - V_{th}\$:
[image: Graph of the relationship between Vds and Id for Vgs - Vth in {1, ..., 7}]
*(By User:CyrilB - File:IvsV_mosfet.png, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=15316422)*

However, when I run a simulation using the [STN3N45K3](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stn3n45k3.pdf) N-channel MOSFET, the result is quite different:
[image: Same graph, but in LTspice]
$$V_{ds}$$

The seven curves are for \$V_{gs} - V_{th} \in \{1, \ldots, 7\} V\$.

I'm assuming \$V_{th} = 3V\$, which is the minimum according to the datasheet:
[image: Minimum: 3V; typical: 3.75V, Maximum: 4.5V]

Here's my circuit:
[image: .step param Vgs 4 10 1; .dc Vds 0 10 0.01; Vgs is connected to R1 (21 ohms), connected to the gate; Vds is connected to the drain; the source is connected to ground]

Why is this happening?

Side note: I don't have a formal education with MOSFETS, nor have I read any books. I'm just trying to understand the basics of how they behave so I can use them in simple circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing with the curves in the data sheet: -

[image]

They look closer to the simulation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the STN3N45K3 that I used in LTspice and found Vth ~4.47V. I don't know if LTspice randomizes the values from device to device.

If you extend your VDS axis out to greater than 25V, it should look very similar to the datasheet